# Is using @ (at) operator a bad idea?

Tags: php

Is writing:

```
$name = @$_GET['name'];
```

instead of:

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : null;
```

is some bad coding practice? Can I use @ as a normal operator or only in some specific cases?

Comment: The `@` in the first blurb is hardly the only bad coding practice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, using the `@` operator is considered bad practice.

It is well documented that it has performance implications.

In addition, supressing error messages is a sign of bad practice; you should write your code to expect errror and handle them defensively. Simply swallowing the errors behind an `@` symbol means that your code will never know that the error occurred, nor what the error actually was; this can often lead to further problems later in your code.

There are some cases where it is unavoidable to use `@` but this is not one of them, so you should avoid doing it.